# How to plot a composite image made with aplot on R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I made a composite image (dendrogram + heatmap) and I plotted them together using aplot package, more precisely with the command insert_left(). The plot comes out pretty well, but I can't save it using neither postscript() nor ggsave(). With postscript I get a blank image, with ggsave I only get the dendrogram. I would like to save it as .ps or .eps.

Below I put the code i used to plot the image. Can someone please help me with this?

```
R session: 
$mode
[1] "server"

$version
[1] ‘2023.3.1.446’

$long_version
[1] "2023.03.1+446"

$release_name
[1] "Cherry Blossom"



heatmap <- ggplot(otz.scaled, aes(x = sample, y = asv)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = abundance)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", limits = col.range)+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
    angle = 90,
    vjust = 0.5,
    hjust = 1
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())

tree <- ggtree(x.cl)
tree <- groupClade(tree, clades)


plot <- heatmap %>% insert_left(tree)
plot

postscript(
  file = "heatmap.eps",
  paper = "special",
  width = 10,
  height = 20,
  horizontal = F
)

ggsave(
  "dendroheatmap",
  device = "ps",
  path = "/home/path/path",
  width = 12,
  height = 8,
  dpi = 300,
  units = "cm"
)
```

I didn't manage to create a small enough dput() output to paste here, hope you can help anyway!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What code exactly are you using to save the plot?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to paste a small enough dataset here with dput(). I hope it is not a problem. I included as much info as i could. Sorry but I am new to asking questions here!